# ¿Cómo llegó "perendengue" a significar "pendiente" a partir de "pender"?

Tags: etimología, ropa

Escuchando la fantastiquísima [*El día que nací yo*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OXccvUDexY) del asturiano Rodrigo Cuevas, el *agitador folklórico* (así se define él) me encuentro en [el minuto 1:50](https://youtu.be/4OXccvUDexY?t=113):

> De todos los mozos de montera, no había otro que se la acomparase en el aire de llevarla
>   Que habría chalecos con mejores agramanes y más **perendengues** en la cadena
>   Pero a ninguno le asentaban como a él le iban

Nunca había oído *perendengue*, así que consultando el DLE vi:

> [**perendengue**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=perendengue)
>   *Der. de pender.*
>
> 1. m. pendiente (‖ arete).
> 2. m. Adorno femenino de poco valor.
> 3. m. Moneda de vellón que se acuñó en tiempo de Felipe IV, y valía cuatro maravedís.
> 4. m. pl. Adornos, atavíos.
> 5. m. pl. Requilorios, dificultades, trabas.

Por contexto, diría que su uso encaja con la cuarta acepción (*adornos, atavíos*). Sin embargo, me resulta curioso su etimología: indica que viene de [*pender*](https://dle.rae.es/pender) (*Dicho de una cosa: Estar colgada, suspendida o inclinada*). Sin embargo, el salto *pender* → *perendengue* parece necesitar algunos saltos intermedios. ¿Cuáles fueron?

Comment: Ni idea — al inicio pensaba que tal vez sería de *per + ende + ca* (por desde allí (hasta) aquí) porque *perendega* es una prostituta, y de allí adornos quizás, pero no lo creo, sobre todo siendo una palabra antigua.  La introducción de una *e* no sería del todo imposible, como forma de facilitar la pronunciación, pero el sufijo   El cantante una joya, he hablado con él ya varias veces.  Es super reivindicativo de la cultura rural y tradicional (cosa que vive literalmente viviendo en un monte con su burro), aunque sus vídeos tienen unas tendencias muy modernas y eléctricas.

Comment: @user0721090601 vi hace poco a Rodrigo en directo. Un espectáculo que me dejó impresionado, es buenísimo. Canta bien, toca también, tiene muchísima conciencia y además es incluso muy divertido. Un lujazo